# inheritance of customized module in openerp

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have successfully created module  and it is working absolutely fine. Now from that module i have inheritated another module for which i need your support for xml genaration. I have given original module .py and xml file along with new module .py file. Please provide me the xml for new module

ORIGINAL module .py file

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class test_base(osv.osv):
    _name='test.base'
    _columns={
        'name':fields.char('Name'),
        'email':fields.char('Email'),

        'code':fields.integer('Unique ID'),
        'sal':fields.float('Salary'),
        'rate':fields.selection(((10,'10'), (20,'20'),(30,'30')),
               'Percentage of Deduction'),
        'ded':fields.float('Deduction'),
        'bdisplay':fields.float('Button Display'),

}

    def on_change_ded_cal(self, cr, uid, ids,rate,context=None):
        x=rate*2
        return {'value':{'ded':x }}


test_base()
```

original module xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_form">
       <field name="name">test.base.form</field>
           <field name="model">test.base</field>
           <field name="type">form</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="Test Base">                       
                   <field name="name"/>
                   <field name="email"/>
                   <field name="code"/>
                   <field name="sal"/>
                   <field name="rate" on_change="on_change_ded_cal(rate)"/>
                   <field name="ded"/>                       
                   <field name="bdisplay"/>                    
                  </form>
          </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_tree">
        <field name="name">test.base.tree</field>
        <field name="model">test.base</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Test Base">               
               <field name="name"/>
                <field name="email"/>
                <field name="code"/>
                <field name="sal"/>          
                <field name="ded"/>                    
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_test_seq">
        <field name="name">Test Base</field>
        <field name="res_model">test.base</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
    <menuitem id="menu_test_base_main" name="Test Base" action="action_test_seq"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_test_base" parent="menu_test_base_main"
              name="Test Base1" action="action_test_seq"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

New module .py file

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields
class my_base(osv.osv):
    _name='my.base'
_inherit='test.base'
    _columns={
        'dept':fields.char('Department'),       

        }       
my_base()
```

(new field 'dept can be added after 'ded' field also please explain on xml id's)

Comment: "I'm confused with new module xml especially with id's [sic]". That is *not* a question. Be more specific: what are you having trouble with; what have you written; how do you know it doesn't work (errors, unexpected outputs...)?

Comment: My question is given here.... May I get xml for the new module.

Comment: Do you mean you want someone to write the xml version of the new module for you? That is not what StackOverflow is for; read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have inherited the `test.base` model and its functionality to `my.base`. So `my.base` will be considered as a new model and you have define a new view for your `my.base` model. You cannot inherit the view of `test.base`. If you are trying to add a new field to the `test.base` model, then from your `my_base() class` remove the _name attribute or change the name attribute to `_name ='test.base'`. Then you can inherit the view of test.base model to add the new field. For example you want to add new field 'dept' to the tree view of test.base, then

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_tree_inheirt">
    <field name="name">test.base.tree</field>
    <field name="model">test.base</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="<base_module_name>.test_base_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="email" position="after">
            <field name="dept"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Here base_module_name is the name of the module where the original view with id test_base_tree is defined. If it is in the same module then no need to provide the module name, just the view id. In this way you can also inherit the form view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me a lot.Replaced my xml with your code for tree view and same way prepared for form view too.  I sincerely appreciate your knowledge.Probably you can understand situation of beginners.  if you don't mind can you  xml where in I wanted to go with new  class my.base .As you mentioned in that i can't inherited view of test base. How I can have new view ?

Comment: For your class my.base, you have to define new view just like the view for the model test.base. In the new view you can add all the fields defined in test.base and also the fields defined in my.base.

Comment: Cool. I got to know this concept. Thanks again for helping me by fixing this inherited view issue as well as other related useful info on this.

Comment: for the scenario _name attribute = original class name  ,I have observed that original view is also updated along with new view .Is there anyway to prevent this ?  I have also noticed that when _name attribute != original class name , original view is not updated.

Comment: if _name attribute = original class name, and we inherit the view, then the original view will be updated.If you want you can create new view with old and new fields. Then original(old) view will not get affected. To get new form view, you need to pass context attribute = "{'form_view_get':'<module_name>.new_form_view_xmlid'}" from the views.